# How to extract the image IBM Watson detected in the object detection model?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio, visual-recognition

I have created and trained an object detection model in IBM Watson studio to detect a specific part of images. I was wondering how would I then extract that detected image and store it as a separate image? Is there something built into IBM Watson that does this or would I have to use something else to integrate the model with? If I do have to use something else, what would that be and how would I do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IBM Watson doesn't have anything to do that extraction that I'm aware of. But a quick search showed a few utilities that can do that. The [API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition/visual-recognition-v4#analyze-images) returns the `location` of the detected object as a bounding box with X and Y positions and width and height.

Comment: Thank you! As a follow-up, What application or software that is compatible with IBM Watson Studio can I use that is able to utilize these coordinates to extract the image?

Comment: I don't know that there's anything built into Watson Studio to support this. I think that you'll need to get the details from by using the API. However, take a look at help topic at https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/visual-recognition-development.html